# php get variables in google search

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I have a site that allows users to create profile pages.  They do this by submitting an html form that dumps pictures, text, etc into a mqsql database. When they go to their profile they visit (for example): 
www.mysite.com/profile.php?id=104

in profile.php I have a keywords meta tag that populates with some searchable info:

meta name="keywords" content=$username ...

Is it possible to have each profile show up in a Google search doing it this way?  It seems like YouTube does this similarly.

Unless Google searches profile.php with each id they wouldn't know what is in my password protected database.

Any suggestions or feedback would be much appreciated!

Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is no different than any other visitor of your website, so if your website does not contain links to the profile pages, Google will not find and index those pages (unless, of course, someone has posted a link to his/her profile page on another website).

You can 'assist' Google in finding pages on your website by creating a (dynamically generated) sitemap.xml file;

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184

However, if profile pages are protected and only accessible for logged-in Users, then Google will not have access to those pages. You can make an exception for the Google-bot and allow it access without logging in, but you should *not* do so. First of all, it's easy for other people to misuse that and access private information. Second, if Google finds out you're serving different content for Google Bots, you'll get a penalty and may not get indexed at all.

One last remark: ask yourself if users of your site *want* their profile pages to be indexed. I don't know the purpose of your website, but always take this into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I think that a dynamically created sitemap.xml is the way to go in my case.

Comment: Dynamically generated sitemap is what I did and that worked.  Thank you for the suggestion thaJeztah!